# How to catch browser close in Liferay?

Tags: events, liferay, hook, logout

I am catching user logouts with hook with

logout.events.post=...

action and this works.

But also I want to catch browser close as logout too.

How can I accomplish this?

servlet.session.destroy.events=

is not fired I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. I don't think there is an event that can be fired when the user is closing a tab or browser because there is no notification by the browser that the user closed out a window.

Comment: I found that sessions are closed approximately in an hour after close, but don't know how to deduce user to which session was belong to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser close happens on the client... and the session may not have been destroyed (user may not have logged out).

On the client side, you may want to do

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     make_an_ajax_call_to_server_to_notify();
     return null;//to close
     //OR
     //return "Do you really want to close?" to let user click an "Ok" button
}
```